# python is giving me an incorrect value (fredapi)

Tags: python

I'm new to python and am trying to get the same output as the following link:

> https://fred.stlouisfed.org/graph/?g=f1cZ#0

However, when I run my code, it's outputting the wrong value. fredapi's only function is grabbing values from the Fed's website. Anyways, here's the code:

```
from fredapi import Fred
fred = Fred(api_key="...")
data3 = fred.get_series_latest_release("GDPC1")
data4 = fred.get_series_latest_release("GDPPOT")
realgdp = (float(data3.tail(1)))
gdppot = (float(data4.tail(1)))
input1 = 100 * (realgdp - gdppot) / gdppot
```

data3 is just getting the most recent value for GDPC1 here:
[1](https://fred.stlouisfed.org/series/GDPC1)

data 4 is just getting the most recent value for GDPPOT:
[2](https://fred.stlouisfed.org/series/GDPPOT)

The value python is giving me is -16.836765064557746, when it should be -.44 due to the date of data4 not being the same as data3. How can I change the code so that data4's date = data3's date?

Comment: I haven't used this library, but it seems like it's unclear where the problem is exactly. Are `data3` and `data4` incorrect, or is your calculation incorrect? In other words, why are you expecting -.44?

Comment: It's data4 (gdppot). The value it is giving me is for the latest 2031 data release, when it should be the same release as the data3(realgdp) value

Comment: @JamieC113 please add relevant tags in the post.